# How to render only chosen axis labels in ios Charts

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

Library I'm using: [charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts)
I have line chart with values at specific days in year. I don't want to draw each day as label on x axis (there may be more than 300 days range) so I'm looking to draw months only. Right now, my xVals looks like: [nil, nil, nil, "07/2016", nil nil nil (..)]. Unfortunately, no label are displayed.
Is there any other way to achieve desired behaviour?


Code (x axis values):

```
while date.compare(to) != NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending { // iterate over all days in range
        let components = currentCalendar.components([.Day, .Month , .Year], fromDate: date)
        if components.day != 1 {
            vals.append(nil)
        } else { // first day of the month
            vals.append(String(components.month) + " / " + String(components.year))
        }

        let incrementComponents = NSDateComponents()
        incrementComponents.day = 1
        date = currentCalendar.dateByAddingComponents(incrementComponents, toDate: date, options: [])!
}
```

And entries:

```
for point in base!.points {
        if let index = chartValuesFormatter?.indexFromDate(point.date) {
            entries.append(ChartDataEntry(value: point.value, xIndex: index))
        }
}
```

Generally it works, when I specify all values some of them are displayed and entries are rendered correctly. My only problem is to display only month labels on the beginning of month periods.

Comment: just put the month for all the value, the lib will choose approtiate number of value to show

Comment: But sometimes it will show same month more than once. I need to show month labels on 1st of each month (or less ofter if there is too many months - that is something library should optimize on its own).

Comment: Can you please paste some code about how are you creating the data.

Comment: Then maybe you should replace the nil with "" and try again

Comment: @Jassi code samples added

Comment: @Tj3n It was my first attempt ;) Same result.

Comment: oh right, probably it take those nil and "" value to replace to the long text

Comment: @Tj3n Exactly what I suspect. I'm looking at axis renderer, maybe this is the right way. I just wish there is a simpler solution (as this is quite common? charts problem).

Comment: I think you can use `setLabelsToSkip` to skip a number of labels to showing, its the best way i can think of, for a month then that value should be 28 or 29

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120503/discussion-between-maciej-koziel-and-tj3n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I've found solution. It's not as simple as is should (for such basic problem), but is very customizable.
`LineChartView (via BarLineChartViewBase)` has property `xAxisRenderer`. You can subclass `ChartXAxisRenderer` which is default one, and override `drawLabels` function. In my case, I've copied original code and modified logic behind calculation what label and where should be drawn.

Edit: My custom renderer with overlap logic. Probably overcomplicated, but it works so far.

```
class ChartXAxisDateRenderer: ChartXAxisRenderer {
internal static let FDEG2RAD = CGFloat(M_PI / 180.0)

/// draws the x-labels on the specified y-position
override func drawLabels(context context: CGContext, pos: CGFloat, anchor: CGPoint) {

    guard let xAxis = xAxis else { return }

    let paraStyle = NSParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle().mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
    paraStyle.alignment = .Center

    let labelAttrs = [NSFontAttributeName: xAxis.labelFont,
                      NSForegroundColorAttributeName: xAxis.labelTextColor,
                      NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paraStyle]
    let labelRotationAngleRadians = xAxis.labelRotationAngle * ChartXAxisDateRenderer.FDEG2RAD

    let valueToPixelMatrix = transformer.valueToPixelMatrix

    let minLabelsMargin: CGFloat = 4.0

    var position = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)

    var labelMaxSize = CGSize()

    if (xAxis.isWordWrapEnabled) {
        labelMaxSize.width = xAxis.wordWrapWidthPercent * valueToPixelMatrix.a
    }

    var positions = [CGPoint]()
    var widths = [CGFloat]()
    var labels = [String]()
    var originalIndices = [Int]()

    for i in 0...xAxis.values.count-1 {
        let label = xAxis.values[i]
        if (label == nil || label == "")
        {
            continue
        }

        originalIndices.append(i)
        labels.append(label!)

        position.x = CGFloat(i)
        position.y = 0.0
        position = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(position, valueToPixelMatrix)
        positions.append(position)

        let labelns = label! as NSString
        let width = labelns.boundingRectWithSize(labelMaxSize, options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: labelAttrs, context: nil).size.width
        widths.append(width)
    }

    let newIndices = findBestPositions(positions, widths: widths, margin: minLabelsMargin)

    for index in newIndices {
        let label = labels[index]
        let position = positions[index]
        let i = originalIndices[index]

        if (viewPortHandler.isInBoundsX(position.x)) {
            drawLabel(context: context, label: label, xIndex: i, x: position.x, y: pos, attributes: labelAttrs, constrainedToSize: labelMaxSize, anchor: anchor, angleRadians: labelRotationAngleRadians)
        }
    }
}

// Best position indices - minimum "n" without overlapping
private func findBestPositions(positions: [CGPoint], widths: [CGFloat], margin: CGFloat) -> [Int] {
    var n = 1
    var overlap = true

    // finding "n"
    while n < widths.count && overlap {
        overlap = doesOverlap(n, positions: positions, widths: widths, margin: margin)
        if overlap {
            n += 1
        }
    }

    var newPositions = [Int]()
    var i = 0
    // create result indices
    while i < positions.count {
        newPositions.append(i)
        i += n
    }

    return newPositions
}

// returns whether drawing only n-th labels will casue overlapping
private func doesOverlap(n: Int, positions: [CGPoint], widths: [CGFloat], margin: CGFloat) -> Bool {
    var i = 0
    var newPositions = [CGPoint]()
    var newWidths = [CGFloat]()

    // getting only n-th records
    while i < positions.count {
        newPositions.append(positions[i])
        newWidths.append(widths[i])
        i += n
    }

    // overlap with next label checking
    for j in 0...newPositions.count - 2 {
        if newPositions[j].x + newWidths[j] + margin > newPositions[j+1].x {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

}

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience but I have the same problem, could you post your custom code? Thanks!

Comment: @user3745888 posted. Most code is about overlapping, but rest should be quite clear. I guess it's flawed and overcomplicated (it's not well tested yet). Feel free to leave a comment.